# What does "transposition" mean in edit distance algorithm?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk

I am studying **edit distance algorithm** but cannot understand transpositions - what does it mean?

http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/metrics/distance.html

```
def edit_distance(s1, s2, transpositions=False):
```

It is not clearly explained in documentation.

Can you give some simple example to help me understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert GAOL to GOAL:
Without transpositions you must do two edits: delete 'A', insert 'A' after 'O'.
With transpositions you must do one edit: transpose 'A' and 'O'

Comment: For those who have the same as me. Note that only transposition of two ADJACENT characters is allowed ;)